# Android edittext capslock after click space

Tags: android

i use :

> android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapSentences"

the 1st character is capital.
i want it is the same Robert Noe
and if user hit space, the next word 1st character is capital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `textCapWords` to capitalise every word.